# Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app) in vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuetify.js

So I'm building mobile app via veu.js -> vuetify module using realtime database from firebase.

One of my views - Pract.vue need to retrive data from database.

```
<template>
  <div class="pa-6 text-center">
    <h1>Practice Mode</h1>
  </div>
</template>



<script>
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/database";

var ref = firebase.database().ref("ang");


</script>
```

I added firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); with data generated by firebase console to main.js file and import firebase from "firebase"

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import firebase from "firebase";

// Xs in original code are real data

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "X",
    authDomain: "X",
    databaseURL: "X",
    projectId: "X",
    storageBucket: "X",
    messagingSenderId: "X",
    appId: "X",
    measurementId: "X"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    vuetify,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Console alert **Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).**

I've tried **import firebase from 'firebase/app'** both in view and main.js -> same alert.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when trying to use firebase in the router index.ts file. I had to initialize firebase in index.ts to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

- Try changing the import statement to

  ```
  import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
  ```
- I faced the same error while trying to have an separate file for
  accessing firebase services (which is neither a component nor a file created by vue-cli). In my case it is **sampleAPI.ts**. So to solve this, I had to import the above mentioned statement and then initialized the app in **sampleAPI.ts** that solved my problem.

  ```
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  ```

Comment: same issue tried the above solution but no worked